# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed (c# asp.net master pages)

Tags: c#, xml, master-pages, declaration, well-formed

I've been messing around with html for a while, but couldn't find a good way to have a "template" besides using iframes or ajax pages. So I'm trying out c# asp with a master page. my site is working fine on local host but when I upload it I get this error message. other people have gotten a page of code instead of the error message

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: (removed)
Line Number 2, Column 2:
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Vorlof._default" %>
-^
```

I've been searching and reading since yesterday, i've read similar problems on here that mention adding the version and encoding but I'm not sure where to put it.
Thanks in Advance!